# How to create a test only Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

In my directory structure I use src only. And I am only writing up Selenium Junit tests. So I would only be writing test classes. How can I configure maven to test only with src ?

Tried pointing to same output directory, but mvn clean test cannot run the test files.

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
<testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</testOutputDirectory>
```

If I add below entries, I see the project gets built twice.

```
 <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</testSourceDirectory>
```

Comment: The whole point of using Maven is to adhere to convention.  Why can't you just use the conventional directory layout (i.e. `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`)?

Comment: I guess to have clean structure and probably client requirement

Answer (score 0):

Even thus this may be possible using Maven it will brake the underlaying convention. Beeing at the point where a "clean structure" or client requirements deny following the convention i would question Maven as the right choice for your build process.

**BUT:** Most Java developpers would consider the maven structure "clean", expecially because production/busines-code is separated from test code allowing for example to deploy your application including all of the unit- and integrationtests to a Jenkins server for continous integration while a deployment to the production environment may not contain any test classes at all.

Since per definition only "productive" code belongs to `src/main/java` even if you would have some sort of test-base with your own TestRunners, Factorys, etc. under `src/main/java` the according "Tests of the Testbase" would reside in `src/test/java`.

If i was you i would realy consider to refactor the project and move your Testclasses to `src/test/java` (i leave it open to you on how you argument about convention over configuration and related topics :))